# Kivy and audiostream, can't record

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm using [audiostream](https://github.com/kivy/audiostream) but can't manage to record anything from the microphone.

```
def mic_callback(buf):
    print('got', len(buf))
    frames.append(buf)
    print('size of frames: ' + len(frames))

def bcallback(instance):
    mic = get_input(callback=mic_callback, source='mic')
    mic.start()
    #mic.poll()
    time.sleep(5)
    mic.stop()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        btn1 = Button(text='Audio Record')
        btn1.bind(on_press=bcallback)
        return btn1

if name == 'main':
    MyApp().run()
```

Running this bit of code and using `logcat` I can see that `mic_callback` isn't working since there isn't any print on `logcat`.

I've tried to change source to `default` also, but doesn't work either.

Comment: I was reformatting your code--`if name=='main'` is wrong, the syntax is `__name__=='__main__'`. I wonder if the only problem is that your application wasn't even starting.

Comment: The app starts fine, just produces a 44 byte file (empty of course), since the list frames is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after lots of trial and error I've managed to get this thing working. Not sure what fixed it, probably the buffer size. So I figured out the the "mic_callback" wasn't actually being called because there was nothing on the queue. So the problem should be in the configuration of the audio input. This worked for me (since I suck posting here the code I'll use pastebin):
http://pastebin.com/80sFjGWs

Answer (score 0):

I have a code snippet i used for audio recording on android with kivy.
I didn't use audiostream but maybe it is useful in your case.
Unfortunately it doesn't record in wav and you
need to install jnius in order to use the snippet.

The button passed to play() and start() in Player() and Recorder() is just a string with the name of the file Player() and Recorder() are accessing.

```
import os
from jnius import autoclass

if not os.path.isdir("/sdcard/kivyrecords/"):
    os.mkdir("/sdcard/kivyrecords/")

PATH = "/sdcard/kivyrecords/rec{0}.mp4"

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # get the MediaPlayer java class
        self.MediaPlayer = autoclass('android.media.MediaPlayer')

    def play(self, button):
        # create our player
        mPlayer = self.MediaPlayer()
        mPlayer.setDataSource(PATH.format(button))
        mPlayer.prepare()
        mPlayer.start()
        if not mPlayer.isPlaying():
            mPlayer.release()

class Recorder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # get the needed Java classes
        self.MediaRecorder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder')
        self.AudioSource = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$AudioSource')
        self.OutputFormat = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$OutputFormat')
        self.AudioEncoder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$AudioEncoder')

        self.mRecorder = self.MediaRecorder()       

    def start(self, button):
        self.mRecorder.setAudioSource(self.AudioSource.MIC)
        self.mRecorder.setOutputFormat(self.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        self.mRecorder.setOutputFile(PATH.format(button))
        self.mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(self.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC)
        self.mRecorder.prepare()

        self.mRecorder.start()

    def stop(self, button):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.mRecorder.stop()
        self.mRecorder.release()
        self.mRecorder = self.MediaRecorder()
```

edit:

The whole script:

```
#qpy:kivy
'''
Created on 20.06.2015

@author: jan
'''
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.7') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout        

#from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader 

from jnius import autoclass

import os
import time

if not os.path.isdir("/sdcard/kivyrecords/"):
    os.mkdir("/sdcard/kivyrecords/")

PATH = "/sdcard/kivyrecords/rec{0}.mp4"

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # get the MediaPlayer java class
        self.MediaPlayer = autoclass('android.media.MediaPlayer')

    def play(self, button):
        # create our player
        mPlayer = self.MediaPlayer()
        mPlayer.setDataSource(PATH.format(button))
        mPlayer.prepare()
        mPlayer.start()
        if not mPlayer.isPlaying():
            mPlayer.release()

class Recorder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # get the needed Java classes
        self.MediaRecorder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder')
        self.AudioSource = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$AudioSource')
        self.OutputFormat = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$OutputFormat')
        self.AudioEncoder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$AudioEncoder')

        self.mRecorder = self.MediaRecorder()       

    def start(self, button):
        self.mRecorder.setAudioSource(self.AudioSource.MIC)
        self.mRecorder.setOutputFormat(self.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        self.mRecorder.setOutputFile(PATH.format(button))
        self.mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(self.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC)
        self.mRecorder.prepare()

        self.mRecorder.start()

    def stop(self, button):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.mRecorder.stop()
        self.mRecorder.release()
        self.mRecorder = self.MediaRecorder()       

PLAY = Player()
REC = Recorder()
RECORDED = {1 : False, 2 : False, 3 : False, 
                        4 : False, 5 : False, 6 : False,
                        7 : False, 8 : False, 9 : False}

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(cols=3, rows=3)

        global REC
        global RECORDED
        global PLAY

        for i in range(1, 10):
            b = Button(text=str(i))
            b.bind(on_press=self.recorplay)
            b.bind(on_release=self.stop)
            self.add_widget(b, i)

    def recorplay(grid, button):
        if not RECORDED[int(button.text)]:
            REC.start(button.text)
        else:
            PLAY.play(button.text)

    def stop(grid, button):
        if not RECORDED[int(button.text)]:
            REC.stop(button.text)   
            RECORDED[int(button.text)] = True

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I think I've tried that approach and I've got a jnius error importing the java classes, but I'll give your code a try and report the results.

Comment: The example should run on android devices using qpython.
I edit my answer and put a downloadlink to my original script.
It is still a little bit buggy but if you run it on an android device you should be able to record a sound pressing a button. Releasing it stops the record and tapping the button again plays the record.
Hope it helps.
P.s. i usally test my kivy scripts in Qpython. So on Linux or Windows and Mac its not possible to install jnius as far as i know.

Comment: I've tested your script and it works on my android device flawlessly!
I would rather have the audiostream approach for cross-platform, but this is better than not working at all.
Thank you BigZ :)

Comment: Hope someone else comes up with an actual answer to your question because i also would like to use audiostream in order to record wave.
But i'm glad i could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are struggling to find the answer to this question in 2021, take a look at kivy's [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer) repository, especially to the one related with current question of [audio recording](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/tree/master/examples/audio).